# gcloud unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: gcloud

Behind a corporate firewall with Symantec WSS agent.
I get this error

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
Please run:

I tried

`gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation True`

I also pulled the certificate chain with

`openssl s_client -showcerts oauth2.googleapis.com:443`
and then

`gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file c:/temp/certs.pem`

No matter what it won't get past the certificate check
I thought that disabling SSL validation would work, but it doesn't